# Why is there no delimited, integer-only cataloging option in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, search, indexing, integer, catalog

Is there something I'm missing?

What I am trying to create is basically a table of indexes separated by spaces (or whatever type you fancy). I realize that Full Text Search would not be possible on merely int-type data columns because it understands "spaces" as the delimiter to separated data to be indexed across the whole catalog.

I do realize that it does allow me to index `varbinary` type data, but why not just `int` data separated by spaces, rather than include integer AND text data to search through. IE, a

```
 SEARCH * FROM MyTable
 WHERE CONTAINS(indexedcolumn, '1189')
```

with a full text index/catalog defined for a table that looks like:

```
 indexedColumn      secondDelimitedIntColumn
 1189               34 34209 1989 3 5
```

is not possible, but

```
 SEARCH * FROM MyTable
 WHERE CONTAINS(uniqueColumn, 'a1189')
```

WOULD work using the full text index on a table with the following columns:

```
 uniqueColumn secondDelimitedIntColumn
 a1189        b34 b34209 b1989 b3 b5
```

so basically executing a `CONTAINS()` search on any column with a full text index on it will work only if there is some text attached to the integer string.

But my question is asking "Why can't I just used strings of integers separated by spaces, which saves me the step of having to add dummy text just to get trick SQL Server into allowing me to execute a full text search on indexed integer strings?"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. LIKE on integers ? There is probably a better way, try posting an example of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I'm saying why isn't there a way to create catalogs of data where each delimited datum can be indexed, like in Full Text Search/Catalog/Indexing. LIKE would be the only method to search a column full of delimited integers without me writing my own parsing search function, as far as I can see (which wouldn't be helpful, because you can't index each delimited item in this way, and LIKE is supposedly pretty slow to begin with).

Comment: Columns in the database are delimiters for values. That is the design of the relational databases. If you want anything else, you are doing it wrong, or need another tool.

Comment: So you're storing a list of integers in a non-relational way (a delimited list), and you want a relational database to work better with that construct? Have you considered storing them as a set and using, e.g., table-valued parameters? Your application can still treat them as comma-delimited strings but the database doesn't have to.

Comment: "*catalogs of data where each delimited datum can be indexed*". You already have it, its called a TABLE

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name no, that is NOT a table, because I have a column housing *integers separated by spaces as delimiters*, which is not the same, because when you create a full text index on that column, it changes the nature of the way SQL is indexing the data. This Full text index is giving each space-separated string of data its own index, whereas traditional tables are indexing cells, not understanding what is in them (except slightly for clustering purposes)

Comment: @driis, I'm trying to create a catalog here for a reason...look at the format of the cells in the example [here] (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315101/SQL-Full-Text-Search-Programming) . each string within that column is indexed. that's what makes Full Text index greater than using "LIKE", because it introduces a new index format on the cells

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks so much for not making me feel like this is a bogus attempt at something simple. My database structure is very complex, and takes a lot of explanation, which is why I haven't already. But your response is right, I just don't know what you mean by "storing them as table value parameters." Because the data in each integer string is actually imported from a look up library table, and i am combining an indefinite number of these library indexes to create a GUID sort of code, i need a way to quickly pick out relevant matches (searching within the cell itself, too)

Answer (score 6):

This isn't really a question. There are no details about the query you are attempting run or the schema you are running it out of. I'm not exactly sure what to tell you here. I might be able to help you if there are some details available. It's more like you have a complaint than a question.

I'm fully aware this should be in the comments section and not answer but I don't have the points for that on overflow. I live on .dba.

Comment: I apologize for that being unclear, I edited the question and hopefully this will make more sense. Not trying to complain, just have a huge need for being able to have a full text search column, or in my case, more of a full "integer" search column separated by spaces. This does not seem possible, even if creating a full text index on a varbinary type data column. I don't want to have to jump through hoops and reformat the strings of integers I have into varbinary types, etc. just to get the full text search to recognize them. Thank you for responding!

Comment: Ok so when you are using these coma delimited rows in a nosql database row 1 looks like this (1,2,3,4,5) and it uses full text search to look through there for what you need. In a RDBM your going to set up things a little differently. Row 1 will have int (1) Row 2 will have int (2) and so on and so forth. hope that helps you see what we are saying.

Comment: what do you mean "Row 1 will have int1...." ? are you saying each one of those delimited items (1,2,3,...n) each get their own index? Yes that is what I am trying to achieve but in sql. Thanks so much for stayin with me. There is other software out there that does this, such as IDL and Matlab (--everything is in Arrays). Like I said though, my hands are tied to MS SQL :( Please respond in answer form so I can upvote you later! I've never used NoSQL, also.

Comment: You have to set it so that each comma delimited value will be its own row. You then search through the rows in your column to get that result.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated with XML example, below**

Your current design violates [1st normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Domains_and_values).

That, in itself, is okay.  Over some years, I've inherited and had to maintain several systems that did so.  I don't know why they were built that way.  It doesn't really matter.  They had to be maintained and the schedule wasn't always such that there was time for refactoring, testing and validation, not to mention doing so for the stack of apps that were built upon them.

Looking back now, though, I can easily spot the one attribute that they all shared.  It was the absolute biggest barrier to optimizing and extending these systems: **the underlying "relational" database violated 1st normal form**. Virtually every technical "gotcha" encountered, virtually every performance problem, it was *the* root cause.  Splitting strings.  Creating a faux datatype system to validate them.  Creating further delimited attributes to describe them.  Creating special rules for each delimited "location" and having to implement an EVAL function in many systems to enforce them.  Using dynamic SQL or worse to search it all.  It took more "clever" programming to implement what seemed like conceptually simple features than I care to recollect.

Maybe your system is different.  Maybe [40+ years of relational database research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_F._Codd#Work) does not apply to your situation.  For your sake, I truly hope so.  The only problem is that you're using a relational database in a non-relational way.  Just like you can pound screws with a hammer, and you can pull a boat with a motorcycle (don't hit the brakes if you actually get it going), you can create an index (full-text or b-tree) on text that represents integers.

But why would you do any of these things?  Why wouldn't you actually store the integers as integers and enjoy type-safety?  Why wouldn't you normalize this into two related tables to take advantage of smaller transactions and more indexing options?  If you've inherited a system that you can't change, then please say so and people might be able to help with alternatives (TVPs and XML been rightfully mentioned).  But I can't see coming into the situation saying that your hammer and motorcycle are broken because they don't drive screws and pull boats very well.

All that said (maybe *somebody, somewhere* is rethinking an ill-advised design), I've put `LIKE` to good use when searching delimited strings:

```
-- Setup demo data
declare @delimitedInts table (
    data varchar(max) not null
)
insert into @delimitedInts select '0,1,2'
insert into @delimitedInts select '1,2,3,4'
insert into @delimitedInts select '5,10'

-- Create a search term
declare @searchTerm int = 2

-- Get all rows that contain the searchTerm
select data
from @delimitedInts
where ',' + data + ',' like '%,' + cast(@searchTerm as varchar(11)) + ',%'

-- Create many search terms
declare @searchTerms table (
    searchTerm int not null primary key
)
insert into @searchTerms select 2
insert into @searchTerms select 3
insert into @searchTerms select 4

-- Get all rows that contain ANY of the searchTerms
select distinct a.data
from @delimitedInts a
    join @searchTerms b on ',' + a.data + ',' like '%,' + cast(b.searchTerm as varchar(11)) + ',%'

-- Get all rows that contain ALL of the searchTerms
select a.data
from @delimitedInts a
    join @searchTerms b on ',' + a.data + ',' like '%,' + cast(b.searchTerm as varchar(11)) + ',%'
group by a.data
having count(*) = (select count(*) from @searchTerms)
```

Is this too slow for you?  Maybe.  Have you actually [measured it](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/why-arent-my-optimizations-optimizing.html)?  At least you could get an implementation in place and [prove that it works before you optimize it](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MakeItWorkMakeItRightMakeItFast).

**Update: XML**

I've done a little testing on converting your space-delimited column to an XML column and querying it, including doing so with [XML indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345121.aspx).  Unfortunately, you can't put an XML index on a computed column, so I'm using a trigger to keep an XML column automatically updated.  Here are some interesting results (note the SQL comments):

```
-- Create a demo table
create table MyTable (
      ID int not null primary key identity
    , SpaceSeparatedInts varchar(max) not null
    --, ComputedIntsXml as cast('<ints><i>' + replace(SpaceSeparatedInts, ' ', '</i><i>') + '</i></ints>' as xml) persisted -- Can't use XML index
    , IntsXml xml null
)
go
-- Create trigger to update IntsXml
create trigger MyTable_Trigger on MyTable after insert, update as begin
    update m
    set m.IntsXml = cast('<ints><i>' + replace(m.SpaceSeparatedInts, ' ', '</i><i>') + '</i></ints>' as xml)
    from MyTable m
        join inserted i on m.ID = i.ID
end
go
-- Add some demo data
insert into MyTable (SpaceSeparatedInts) select '1'
insert into MyTable (SpaceSeparatedInts) select '1 2'
insert into MyTable (SpaceSeparatedInts) select '2 3 4'
insert into MyTable (SpaceSeparatedInts) select '5 6 7 10'
insert into MyTable (SpaceSeparatedInts) select '100 10 1000'
go

-- Search for the number 10 (and use this same query in subsequent testing, below)
select *
from MyTable
where IntsXml.exist('/ints/i[. = "10"]') = 1
-- This query spends virtually all of its time running an XML Reader and an XPath filter

-- Add a primary xml index
create primary xml index IX_MyTable_IntsXml on MyTable (IntsXml)
-- The query now uses a clustered index scan and clustered index seek on PrimaryXML

-- Add secondary xml index for value
create xml index IX_MyTable_IntsXml_Value on MyTable (IntsXml) using xml index IX_MyTable_IntsXml for value
-- No change

-- Add secondary xml index for path
create xml index IX_MyTable_IntsXml_Path on MyTable (IntsXml) using xml index IX_MyTable_IntsXml for path
-- No change

-- Add secondary xml index for property
create xml index IX_MyTable_IntsXml_Property on MyTable (IntsXml) using xml index IX_MyTable_IntsXml for property
-- The query now replaces the clustered index scan on PrimaryXML with an index seek on SecondaryXML
```

While it is clearly a different method, is this faster than LIKE?  You have to test in your environment.  Hopefully this will give you some ideas of how to do so.  Please let me know how this works out for you, if it's doable in your shop.

Comment: [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394420/best-approach-for-doing-full-text-search-with-list-of-integers-documents) is almost exactly analogous to what I was asking. I'm saying I had an indefinite number of things on the right-hand column assigned to a one thing on the left-hand column. This question should not have been closed.

Comment: Reading your question once again, I still view it as saying, "Why won't my relational database help me violate 1st normal form?"  I would imagine you'd get much the same reaction if you asked [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com/), "Why won't my hammer pound screws?"

Comment: That said, I'll post an XML example hopefully soon.

Comment: @ Tim Lehner -- If I knew 100% that my hammer wouldn't pound screws but it was the best tool in my toolbox of hammer, pen, screw, ruler , then I would continue to use my hammer :) fyi, the post [here] is analogous to what I'm trying to achieve in sql.

Comment: @UB3571, please let me know if the XML example that I've just added makes anything possible for you.

Comment: You also might try to get the question reopened by editing it to focus on what _may be possible_ for your situation, rather than what you already know is impossible to do in SQL Server (and unnecessarily disparaging a perfectly fine _relational_ database product in the process).

Comment: I don't see how this disparages MS SQL. If i didn't like SQL, I wouldn't be working so hard to use an already existing feature of it so that I wouldn't have to switch over to something else. What I am doing is still what i believe to be relational. I just can't give you the whole backstory. Just trying to figure out how  to hopefully implement a beautiful system here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I understand what you are looking for either but if you want to store multiple values in a single column, your best bet is going to be to use XML.

See this post for more info on the concept.

[Querying XML columns in SQLServer 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084/querying-xml-columns-in-sqlserver-2005)

Comment: Thanks so much, @Gizmo -- I think that is closer to what I am looking for, in addition to Aaron Bertrand 's comment about Table Value Parameters. The number of items in each cell I am delimiting is of variable length, and I want to be able to index each of those in-cell items like in a full text catalog index, which allows me to search MUCH faster than traditional "LIKE." Parsing is also a very time consuming process, when there's already a faster way: Full Text Search (basically I add some text character to my int string when I put it in the table to make it searchable")

Comment: Can't upvote you and @Aaron Bertrand yet but will when I have more points! Although I think that there isn't a real solution to this in MS SQL yet.